# Javascript: How to get a value from a function inside a method

Tags: javascript, function, sqlite, methods, nested

I trying to get the value (true or false) from nested functions inside of a method, but value returns UNDEFINED. How I can get a value from a object nested function?

```
var result = { 

        compute: function() {
            this.retorno = result.transaction();
        },

        transaction: function() {

            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'database.db', location: 'default'}); 

            db.transaction(checaFR,erroFR); //Check if (F)irst (R)un.                                

            function checaFR(tx){           //Check if table exists
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM setup',[],checaFRSuccess,erroFR2);
                alert("Select Query OK");

            }

            function erroFR(err){           //Return if error
                alert('Ops - '+err);
                return false;               //This value I Need! :(
            }

            function checaFRSuccess(tx,result){
                alert("Query Sucess "+result.rows.length);
                return ('Rows: '+result.rows.length);
            }

            function erroFR2(err2) {        //If no DB table

                alert("erroFR2: "+JSON.stringify(err2));
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);  //Start DB Populate
            }

            function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setup (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, runned TEXT NOT NULL)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO setup(runned) VALUES ("1")');
            }

            function errorCB(errCB) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+errCB);
                return false;                  //This value I Need! :(
            }

            function successCB() {
                alert("successCB OK");
                return true;                   //This value I Need! :(
            }

        }
    };  
    result.compute();                          //Start the main function

return {
    retorno: "var: "+result.retorno      //This returns UNDEFINED
     };
```

How I can get the value from this function and pass it?

Note: All callbacks and alerts are working, including the database creation. :D

Comment: Please reduce the code in the question to a [mcve] and add a clear, single example of what value you need (along with how you've tried to get it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the function nested inside using the following code.

```
result.transaction().erroFR();
result.transaction().errorCB();
```

But **before** that you need to **return the Object** from the inner function which needs to be publicly accessible. This is basically a module pattern, where you can expose only the relevant information to outside world. So you need to expose the functions as shown below. Note the return statement at the end of the function which is returning an object.

```
var result = { 

        compute: function() {
            this.retorno = result.transaction();
        },

        transaction: function() {

            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'database.db', location: 'default'}); 

            db.transaction(checaFR,erroFR); //Check if (F)irst (R)un.                                

            function checaFR(tx){           //Check if table exists
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM setup',[],checaFRSuccess,erroFR2);
                alert("Select Query OK");

            }

            function erroFR(err){           //Return if error
                alert('Ops - '+err);
                return false;               //This value I Need! :(
            }

            function checaFRSuccess(tx,result){
                alert("Query Sucess "+result.rows.length);
                return ('Rows: '+result.rows.length);
            }

            function erroFR2(err2) {        //If no DB table

                alert("erroFR2: "+JSON.stringify(err2));
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);  //Start DB Populate
            }

            function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setup (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, runned TEXT NOT NULL)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO setup(runned) VALUES ("1")');
            }

            function errorCB(errCB) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+errCB);
                return false;                  //This value I Need! :(
            }

            function successCB() {
                alert("successCB OK");
                return true;                   //This value I Need! :(
            }

            // Return an object containing functions which needs to be exposed publicly
            return {
               checaFR : checaFR,
               erroFR : erroFR,
               checaFRSuccess : checaFRSuccess,
               erroFR2 : erroFR2,
               populateDB : populateDB,
               errorCB : errorCB,
               successCB : successCB
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback function into the `result.transaction` method, and the `false` value would be passed into that callback function.

You have to do this bc `false` is derived during/after `db.transaction`, which is an asynchronous method... so we have to pass `false` asynchronously as well.